# Выборка списка по 5 критериям

Tags: c#

У меня есть список List, в котором находятся классы. Мне нужно сделать выборку по 5 критериям, т.е. на формочке у меня есть 5 checkbox-ов, и в зависимости от того, какой из них нажат, должна проводиться выборка. Никак не могу разобраться с написанием условий. Вопрос вроде простой, но решения найти не могу. Вот до чего дошел сам.
Фото формы:

[image]

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBox1.Checked || checkBox2.Checked || checkBox3.Checked || checkBox4.Checked || checkBox5.Checked)
        {


                int Face;
                string category = null;
                string mark = null;
                string model = null;
                string inspection = null;

                if (checkBox1.Checked)
                    Face = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
                else Face = -1;

                if (checkBox2.Checked)
                {
                    foreach (CheckBox che in groupBox1.Controls)
                        if (che.Checked)
                            category += che.Text;
                }
                else category = "";

                if (checkBox3.Checked)
                    mark = textBox1.Text;
                else mark = "";

                if (checkBox4.Checked)
                    model = textBox2.Text;
                else model = "";

                if (checkBox5.Checked)
                    inspection = (checkBox10.Checked) ? "Пройден" : "Не пройден";
                else inspection = null;

                ((Form1)Owner).Reporting(Face, category, mark, model, inspection);
                Close();



        }
    }
}


public void Reporting(int face, string category, string mark,string model,string inspection)
    {

        bool flag;
        bool flag1;
        bool flag2;
        bool flag3;
        bool flag4;
        foreach(Entry En in Entries)
        {
            if (face!=-1)
            {
                if (face == En.Owner.Face)
                    flag = true;
                else flag = false;
            }

            if (category!="")
            {
                if (category == En.Car.category)
                    flag1 = true;
                else flag1 = false;
            }

            if (mark!="")
            {
                if (mark == En.Car.mark)
                    flag2 = true;
                else flag2 = false;
            }

            if (model!="")
            {
                if (model == En.Car.model)
                    flag3 = true;
                else flag3 = false;
            }

            if (inspection!="")
            {
                if (inspection == En.Car.GetInspection())
                    flag4 = true;
                else flag4 = false;
            }
 //-----------------------Решение----------------------------------------------
            var result = Entries.Where(x =>
                       ((face == -1)?true:(x.Owner.Face==face)) &&
                       ((category == "")?true:(x.Car.category==category)) &&
                       ((mark == "")?true:(x.Car.mark==mark)) &&
                       ((model == "")?true:(x.Car.model == model)) &&
                       ((inspection == "")?true:(x.Car.GetInspection() == inspection))); //Большое спасибо за помощь DreamChild

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну наверное что-то такое:

```
var result = Entries.Where(x => 
                           (face == -1 || x.Owner.Face == face) && 
                           (category == "" || x.Car.category == category) &&
                           (mark == "" || x.Car.mark == mark) && 
                           (model == "" || x.Car.model == model) &&
                           (inspection == "" || x.Car.GetInspection() == inspection));
```

Только не забудьте подключить неймспейсы для LINQ

Comment: Эм...  А что в итоге мы получаем в переменной result? И эта конструкция будет работать если например всего один или два из 5 checkbox будет включен.

Comment: Я бы посоветовал использовать вместо сравнения с "" использовать string.IsNullOrEmpty().

Comment: >Эм... А что в итоге мы получаем в переменной result?

**IEnumerable<Entry>**

>И эта конструкция будет работать если например всего один или два из 5 checkbox будет включен

не имею ни малейшего понятия о том, что у вас за чекбоксы. Этот код написан исходя из вашего примера. В нем о чекбоксах нет ни слова

Comment: Добавил код. Теперь вроде понятнее, что происходит. Я проверил ваш код, но он работает, только если все checkbox включены.

Comment: @tsohu обновил ответ

Comment: Все ровно не работает. Тут получается что выполняется условие только тогда, когда все checkbox выбраны. А мне надо, чтобы работало, допустим, при 1 и 3 вкл. checkbox. Вот картинка формы http://rghost.ru/60552130/image.png

Comment: ну так вы нормально сформулируйте, чего вы хотите - я вам не автомат по выдаче готовых решений за вас